# Python: run a bokeh server while handling datainput of widgets

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh

I have a tiny project that gets bigger and bigger. So I decided to split the project into seperate modules. Now I have the problem to manage the event handler .on_change of the bokeh widgets.

**The bokeh app directory looks like:**

```
bokeh_app_test
   |
   +---scripts
   |    +---__init__.py
   |    +---corporates .py
   |
   +---__init__.py
   +---main.py
```

I start the app via Windows cmd : python -m bokeh serve --show bokeh_app_test

Python 3.6.6 Anaconda and Bokeh server version 0.13.0

**main.py:**

```
import datetime
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.models.widgets import Tabs

# scripts
from scripts.corporates import Corporate

# =============================================================================
# definitions
# =============================================================================
StartDate = datetime.date(2018,1,1)
EndDate = datetime.date(2018,8,30)
lLevel1 = ['Corporates', 'Sovereigns', 'Collateralized']

# =============================================================================
# programm code
# =============================================================================
corptab = Corporate(lLevel1,StartDate,EndDate)
corporate_tab = corptab.corp_tab()
tabs = Tabs(tabs = [corporate_tab])
curdoc().add_root(tabs)
```

**and corporates.py**

```
from bokeh.layouts import gridplot
from bokeh.models.widgets import Panel, PreText, DatePicker, Select

class Corporate(object):

    def __init__(self, lLevel1, StartDate, EndDate):
        self.lLevel1 = lLevel1
        self.EndDate = EndDate
        self.StartDate = StartDate
        self.corp_date_picker1 = DatePicker(min_date=self.StartDate,
                          max_date= self.EndDate,
                          value=(self.StartDate),
                          title="Start")
        self.corp_date_picker2 = DatePicker(min_date= self.StartDate,
                          max_date= self.EndDate,
                          value=(self.EndDate),
                          title="End")
        self.corp_level_select = Select(title="Level1:",
                      value="Sovereigns",
                      options=self.lLevel1)
        self.text = PreText(text='', width=1000)

    def corp_date_picker1_change(attrname, old, new):
        self.update_corp_data()

    def corp_date_picker2_change(attrname, old, new):
        self.update_corp_data()

    def corp_level_select_change(attrname, old, new):
        self.update_corp_data()

    def update_corp_data(self):
        StartDate = self.corp_date_picker1.value
        EndDate = self.corp_date_picker2.value
        Level = self.corp_level_select.value

        self.text.text= "StartDate:{}; EndDate:{}; Level: {}".format(StartDate,EndDate,Level)

    def corp_tab(self):
        grid = gridplot([[self.corp_date_picker1, self.corp_date_picker2, self.corp_level_select],
                         [self.text]])
        self.corp_date_picker1.on_change('value', Corporate.corp_date_picker1_change)
        self.corp_date_picker2.on_change('value', Corporate.corp_date_picker2_change)
        self.corp_level_select.on_change('value', Corporate.corp_level_select_change)
        tab = Panel(child=grid, title='TAB 1')
        self.update_corp_data()
        return tab
```

**ERROR**

The server starts without any errors and the widgets show up as supposed:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuLgt.png)

However If I change the values of the widgets then following error pops up:

```
2018-08-30 15:37:24,692 error handling message Message 'PATCH-DOC' (revision 1): NameError("name 'self' is not defined",)
```

thank you
paul

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution:
The .on_change callback function only allows "attr, old, new", however I need self as well. So I cut the callback and pasted it into the main programm.
Does anyone has a better solution?

**main.py**

```
import datetime
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.models.widgets import Tabs

# scripts
from scripts.corporates import Corporate

# =============================================================================
# definitions
# =============================================================================
StartDate = datetime.date(2018,1,1)
EndDate = datetime.date(2018,8,30)
lLevel1 = ['Corporates', 'Sovereigns', 'Collateralized']

# =============================================================================
# programm code
# =============================================================================
corptab = Corporate(lLevel1,StartDate,EndDate)
corporate_tab = corptab.corp_tab()

def corptab_change(attrname, old, new):
        corptab.update_corp_data(corptab.corp_date_picker1.value,
                                 corptab.corp_date_picker2.value,
                                 corptab.corp_level_select.value)
corptab.corp_date_picker1.on_change('value', corptab_change)
corptab.corp_date_picker2.on_change('value', corptab_change)
corptab.corp_level_select.on_change('value', corptab_change)



tabs = Tabs(tabs = [corporate_tab])
curdoc().add_root(tabs)
```

**corporates.py**

```
from bokeh.layouts import gridplot
from bokeh.models.widgets import Panel, PreText, DatePicker, Select

class Corporate(object):

    def __init__(self, lLevel1, StartDate, EndDate):
        self.lLevel1 = lLevel1
        self.EndDate = EndDate
        self.StartDate = StartDate
        self.corp_date_picker1 = DatePicker(min_date=self.StartDate,
                          max_date= self.EndDate,
                          value=(self.StartDate),
                          title="Start")
        self.corp_date_picker2 = DatePicker(min_date= self.StartDate,
                          max_date= self.EndDate,
                          value=(self.EndDate),
                          title="End")
        self.corp_level_select = Select(title="Level1:",
                      value="Sovereigns",
                      options=self.lLevel1)
        self.text = PreText(text='', width=1000)

    def update_corp_data(self, StartDate, EndDate, Level):
        StartDate = StartDate
        EndDate = EndDate
        Level = Level

        self.text.text= "StartDate:{}; EndDate:{}; Level: {}".format(StartDate,EndDate,Level)

    def corp_tab(self):
        grid = gridplot([[self.corp_date_picker1, self.corp_date_picker2, self.corp_level_select],
                         [self.text]])
        tab = Panel(child=grid, title='TAB 1')
        self.update_corp_data(self.corp_date_picker1.value,
                              self.corp_date_picker2.value,
                              self.corp_level_select.value)
        return tab
```